# android8.1: How to register vendor service to ServiceManager

Tags: android, selinux

for android8.1, SELinux permission is more strict. It only allow services defined in plat_service_contexts to register to ServiceManager, we have a vendor service that is register to ServiceManager before, now it will return error when calling defaultServiceManager()->addService as below.

**error:**
04-12 18:07:13.764   268   268 E SELinux : avc:  denied  { add } for service=media.stream pid=649 uid=1013 scontext=u:r:np_mediastream:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:default_android_service:s0 tclass=service_manager permissive=0

if I add this allow sepolicy under /device, will fail to build for below neverallow rule defined in domain.te.

allow np_streammedia default_android_service:service_manager add;

**rule:**
neverallow * default_android_service:service_manager add;

So how to register own vendor service to ServiceManager?

Seems that there are some solutions in google's doc, but I can't understand well.
https://source.android.com/security/selinux/images/SELinux_Treble.pdf

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not so much that SELinux rules changed, but that Treble introduced a new separation of Binder contexts:

1. Framework (`/dev/binder`)
   Only for communication between framework services and apps.
2. Vendor (`/dev/vndbinder`)
   Only for communication between vendor services.
3. Hardware (`/dev/hwbinder`)
   This context is allowed to break the vendor-to-framework barrier. But with a highly improved interface language called `HIDL`.

What you need to do depends on what your service is trying to do.

- If you want to provide a custom `AIDL` interface to apps, you have to make your service a "Framework Extension".
- If you want two of your vendor services to communicate with each other you have to switch to using the vendor context by adding this command before making any Binder calls.

```cpp
ProcessState::initWithDriver("/dev/vndbinder");
```

- If you want to deliver data from a vendor service to a framework service or an app you have to split your service in a vendor service that provides an `HIDL` interface via `/dev/hwbinder` and a framework service that connects to that interface and offers an `AIDL` interface via `/dev/binder`.

Answer (score 1):

SE Linux permissions from Android 8.1 onwards: Go to "/system/sepolicy" directiry

Declare the new type 'my_service' in "public/service.te" file:

```
type my_service, system_api_service,  service_manager_type;
```

In service_contexts("private/service_contexts") file label the service like below:

```
com.android.sampservice.ISampService      u:object_r:my_service:s0
```

Add below rule: (in public/servicemanager.te)

```
allow system_app my_service:service_manager add;
```

In android 8.1 google added a new policy language called the Common Intermediate Language (CIL).
To add a system service you need:
in file system/sepolicy/private/compat/26.0/26.0.cil:  Add

```
(typeattributeset my_service_26_0 (my_service))
```

in file /system/sepolicy/prebuild/api/26.0/nonplat_sepolicy.cil : Add

```
(typeattribute my_service_26_0)       
(roletype object_r my_service_26_0)
```

and add my_service to the line in nonplat_sepolicy.cil file:  Add

```
(typeattributeset service_manager_type (audioserver_service_26_0 , ... , my_service_26_0)
```

Here is the link to explain how to add the system service.
https://devarea.com/aosp-creating-a-system-service/#.XPA50ohKhPZ

Answer (score 0):

> Yes.., For android 8.0 Oreo and above, Registering receivers are not allowed in manifest and static receivers. Need to implement dynamically and runtime from a `STICKY` service, and need to start that service from manifest and a `static receiver` which receives `BOOT_COMPLETED`. Again if you post your code, May be i or some one else would be able to help...!! Please upload code..

Comment: MyMediaService * MyMediaService::instantiate()  {
    MyMediaService * mss = MyMediaService::GetInstance();
    defaultServiceManager()->addService(String16("media.stream "), mss);
    return mss;
}                                Thanks for your answer, but I register this service in native daemon process but not java process. It will be denied by android when calling defaultServiceManager()->addService.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your own service type:

1, define 
http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/device/google/marlin/sepolicy/service.te

```
type cne_service,                 service_manager_type;
```

2, add allow policy
http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/device/google/marlin/sepolicy/qcneservice.te

```
add_service(qcneservice, cne_service)
```

3, label service
http://androidxref.com/8.1.0_r33/xref/device/google/marlin/sepolicy/private/service_contexts

```
cneservice    u:object_r:cne_service:s0
```